# Is there a way to know whether a shape is the rotation of another shape? Or you have to try it out?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I am solving a problem where four small squares are occupying four of the nine small squares in a 3 x 3 plane, the center square must not be occupied and two of the four squares must be located so that the center empty square share two sides with them. The other two squares can be anywhere else. The goal is to find out what is the number of different shapes you can get.

There are two possibilities of locating the two squares near the center, without counting rotations. Including the other 2 squares is harder, but it can be done with time. However, it was time consuming to eliminate all rotations. Is there a way other than rotating shapes in your head to tell whether a shape is a rotation of another shape? Or to come to the conclusion that the two shapes are distinct shapes?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way, than applying $0^\circ, 90^\circ, 180^\circ, 270^\circ$ rotations to the grid, and count the common small squares in each case.  If the number is $4$ then the two grids are rotations of each other.

Comment: This seems like a good application of [Burnside's Lemma](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Burnside%27s_lemma). Your group $G$ here consists of the four rotations mentioned in the previous comment, so for each $g \in G$ you have to count how many among all possible configurations $X$ are *fixed* (*unchanged*) by the given rotation. Then add them up and divide by $|G| = 4$.